# How to export different content depending on redux store to react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list that I use in many places. And i dont want to repeat myself. But its content varies depending on redux store. I tried the option below, but it does not work. How can i fix this?

list.js

```
import store from "./store";

let language = store.getState().language;

store.subscribe(() => {
  language = store.getState().language;
});

export default [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: language === "EN" ? "Hello" : "Hola"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: language === "EN" ? "World" : "Mundo"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: language === "EN" ? "nice to meet you" : "Encantado de conocerte"
  }
];
```

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import list from "./list";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
     {list.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

export dafault App
```

Now i use following approach but i **repeat** this list every time i need it

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const App = () => {
  const language = useSelector((state) => state.language);
  
  const list = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: language === "EN" ? "Hello" : "Hola"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: language === "EN" ? "World" : "Mundo"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: language === "EN" ? "nice to meet you" : "Encantado de conocerte"
  }
];

  return (
    <ul>
     {list.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

export dafault App
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it does not work"? Why doesn't it work? What does it do differently than what you want it to do?

Comment: @AdrianMole, i want App component to rerender with changing redux store but it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exports won't change based on the content of a redux store. Rather than exporting your list, try exporting a function that maps a language to a list. For example:

```
// list.js

export default language => [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: language === "EN" ? "Hello" : "Hola"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: language === "EN" ? "World" : "Mundo"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: language === "EN" ? "nice to meet you" : "Encantado de conocerte"
  }
];
```

```
// app.js
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import getList from "./list";

const App = () => {
  const list = useSelector(state => getList(state.language));
  return (
    <ul>
     {list.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Make sure to wrap your `<App />` in a `<Provider store={store}></Provider>` according to [the react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start).